# this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, surveymonkey

Here is my model class

```
public class SurveyModel
{
    public SurveyModel()
    {
        this.Name = string.Empty;
        this.Url = string.Empty;
    }
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ResponseCount { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public SurveyModel(SurveyMonkey.Containers.Survey survey)
    {
        Name = survey.Nickname;
        ResponseCount = survey.ResponseCount;
        Url = survey.AnalyzeUrl;
    }
```

My contrroller

```
public class SurveysController : Controller
{
    private SurveyMonkeyApi _surveyMonkey;

    public SurveysController(ISurveyMonkeyApiFactory factory)
    {
        // _apiFactory = factory.Create();
    }
    public SurveysController()
    {

    }

    // GET: Surveys

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var api = new SurveyMonkeyApi("zgSdm04SEefy09ONaxV6b0z5rDOoRHXffGXMAasySfAyxUfCTN4x3AR9IyK5NVoRrBKB27bT-SMlbbL0dI2vUNYQiRNZqbslM0-KATC9JwWblgx4mieUwNxoDzC54lxe"))
        {
            IEnumerable<Survey> surveys = api.GetSurveyList();

            return View(surveys.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

My view

```
    @model IEnumerable<SimpleSurveyTest.Models.SurveyModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ResponseCount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Url)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ResponseCount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Url)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Name }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Name }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Name })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I KEEP GETTING this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SurveyMonkey.Containers.Survey]'

but this dictionary requires a model item of type `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[SimpleSurveyTest.Models.SurveyModel]'`

Comment: You are passing **Survey** model in controller, but in view you are expecting **SurveyModel**.

Comment: In the view try replacing  model IEnumerable<SimpleSurveyTest.Models.SurveyModel> with  model IEnumerable<SimpleSurveyTest.Models.Survey> or the Survery entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this method
)
        // GET: Surveys

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var api = new SurveyMonkeyApi("zgSdm04SEefy09ONaxV6b0z5rDOoRHXffGXMAasySfAyxUfCTN4x3AR9IyK5NVoRrBKB27bT-SMlbbL0dI2vUNYQiRNZqbslM0-KATC9JwWblgx4mieUwNxoDzC54lxe"))
    {
        IEnumerable<Survey> surveys = api.GetSurveyList();

        return View(surveys.ToList());
    }
}
```

Exchange

```
return View(surveys.ToList());
```

With

```
return View(surveys.Select(s => new SurveyModel(s)));
```